# What is the meaning of “a lighter schedule”?

Tags: idiomatic-language

I want you guys to help me and tell me about the definition of “a lighter schedule” and give me some examples.

I searched in many websites in google for the meaning but I don’t see any meaning that tell about “a lighter schedule”. Most of all it tells about a busy schedule or etc.

I think it means about a schedule is not so tight and have a free time for doing many things but I don’t sure that it will a correct meaning.

Comment: Have you done any work yourself to figure out what it means? Please tell us what you already know what what you're unsure about. The context where you saw it would help too

Comment: I searched in many websites in google for the meaning but I don’t see any meaning that tell about “a lighter schedule”.Most of all it tells about a busy schedule or etc.

Comment: What do you think it means?

Comment: I think it means about a schedule is not so tight and have a free time for doing many things but I don’t sure that it will a correct meaning.

Comment: Perfect. On this site, we need all that information *in the question*, so I've copied it there for you.

Comment: okey. Thank you so muchhh‍♀️‍♀️

Answer (score 1):

It is exactly as you say.  I schedule that is not so tight, so you have less to do and more free time.

> We have a lighter schedule this week because many of our clients are on holiday.  So I'd like you do some planning for next season in your free time.

Comment: Thank you very much ‍♀️